# Leer array de strings de un fichero binario

Tags: c++

estoy intentando leer un array de strings desde un fichero binario de la siguiente manera:

```
file.read((char*)(&PreguntasJugadas[0]), preguntas_jugadas *  sizeof(string));
```

donde `PreguntasJugadas` es un array de `strings` donde guardar las preguntas y `preguntas_jugadas` es el numero de preguntas a guardar.

El programa crashea cuando hago

```
cout<<PreguntasJugadas[0];
```

El array de strings fue previamente guardado de la siguiente manera:

```
file.write((char*)(&PreguntasJugadas[0]), preguntas_jugadas * sizeof(string));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los [`string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) de la librería estándar no puedes simplemente convertirlos a `char*`.

Si quieres usar una estructura de la librería estándar, sugiero que uses `vector` para almacenar la información y no `string`.

En primer lugar debes darle un tamaño al `vector`. Lo puedes hacer mediante `resize`.

Además, para obtener el puntero al buffer interno, deberías usar la función [`data`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data).

[`sizeof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof) no te da el tamaño de la cadena, sino de la estructura y en bytes.
[`vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) y otros [contenedores](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) de la librería estándar se encargan de reservar su propia memoria a medida que lo necesitan.

Además `sizeof` es una función que se resuelve en tiempo de compilación. Sería imposible que pueda saber el tamaño de una estructura dinámica a menos que estés usando arreglos de tamaño variable.

Puedes usar [`size`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/size) para saber el número de elementos que contiene y en el caso de que necesitaras saber el tamaño en bytes, puedes multiplicar dicho número por el tamaño de un elemento.

Por ejemplo:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<char> str;
    str.resize(4);

    std::cin.read(str.data(), str.capacity());
    std::cout << str.data() << '\n';
    std::cout << str.size() << " caracteres\n";
    std::cout << str.size() * sizeof(char) << " bytes\n";
}
```

Puedes probarlo [aquí](https://tio.run/##fY/LCsIwEEX3@Yqgiya@QBCEtnbtR7gZp2kNtElJR6GKv25Ma6FudFYz9555YdOsS0Tv59pgdc0VT7VtySmoMzZpN4VkXcaYNsRr0EZI/mA8REt5HH/sFC/gsqC4ZLTcxqlW35XYyYRNOGoTDMhFT@RAIORqoBEaQE2dkDL5wu2VeJryie6r6GSiH9CwcoBmHMEBkgp3nMzsP7/gfWIL0f8xtp87Gjuf3h9tBeyFRQVl69dhzAGXy@3@DQ).

En tu código se vería así:

```
file.read(PreguntasJugadas[0].data(), PreguntasJugadas[0].size() *  sizeof(char));
```

Comment: Entonces, si lo que quiero es un vector de strings, necesitaria algo asi: ```std::vector<std::vector<char>>``` no?

Comment: @Franco claro. Recuerda que son vectores. Si quieres aprovechar los strings de C++ necesitarás convertir el vector en uno. Una forma es `std::string(vector.cbegin(), vector.cend())`.

Answer (score 1):

`string` es una **clase** de C++ que usa **memoria dinámica**, es decir, su estado tiene punteros que direccionan memoria, donde se encuentra información de dicho objeto.

Si tu serializas la memoria de un objeto de tipo `string` a pelo, estarás copiando en el archivo el valor de esos punteros, es decir, estarás copiando direcciones de memoria en vez del contenido de dichas direcciones de memoria.

Posteriormente, cuando recuperas el estado del objeto, estarás reasignando los punteros correspondientes ... el problema es que esa memoria muy probablemente ya no contenga la información esperada porque el objeto original ya la habrá liberado o incluso es posible que dicha región de memoria no pertenezca ya a tu proceso, por lo que el Sistema Operativo procederá a matar tu aplicación.

Aun sin usar memoria dinámica, si la clase usa herencia virtual o métodos virtuales, también tendrás problemas al serializar la memoria de los objetos a lo bruto, por lo que no es buena idea hacer esto en C++ salvo que se traten de estructuras simples creadas para la ocasión.

Para serializar un array de strings, una opción puede ser guardar un string por línea de texto:

```
for (std::string pregunta : preguntas_jugadas)
{
    file << pregunta << '\n';
}
```

Y al leer, pues lo mismo, se lee todo por líneas (aquí estoy asumiendo que `preguntas_jugadas` es un array):

```
for (std::string & pregunta : preguntas_jugadas)
{
    std::getline(file, pregunta);
}
```

La diferencia aquí es que no estamos volcando la memoria del `string` sino que estamos recuperando la cadena que almacena dicho objeto, almacenando únicamente dicha cadena.